# Ubuntu shell - Condition to eliminate a line

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting

i have an issue regarding a shell script.sh, i want to create a text file starting with another one. I want to remove specific lines that contains a specific character-sequence from the file. I can eliminate columns with "cut" but what about lines?

```
if [  ???  ] and after that?
```

And if i have a file txt that is ordered with column and line like

name - age - IDs  - sex

1. man1 - 23  - 4532 - M
2. wom1 - 27  - 2300 - F
3. man2 - 40  - 0231 - M

and so on..

how can i eliminate only the lines with age 23 without caring about IDs?

Answer (score 1):

try this awk one-liner:

```
 awk -F' - ' '1*$2!=23' file
```

with your data, it outputs:

```
name - age - IDs - sex
2. wom1 - 27 - 2300 - F
3. man2 - 40 - 0231 - M
```